# docker set a specific ip range with daemon.json

Tags: docker, configuration, ip

I am a little bit confused on how to use a specific ip range for my containers with docker.

I would like to use this range: 172.22.24.1 → 172.22.24.254

Actually, I have this configuration in daemon.json:

```
{
  "default-address-pools": [
    {
      "base": "172.22.24.0/16",
      "size": 24
    }
  ]
}
```

That one give me ip like 172.22.1.3. How can I specify the range 172.22.24.1 → 172.22.24.254 for my containers? (I use docker desktop community edition on mac os)

---

If I use the following configuration:

```
{
  "default-address-pools": [
    {
      "base": "172.22.24.0/24",
      "size": 24
    }
  ]
}
```

I have this error message: "ERROR: could not find an available, non-overlapping IPv4 address pool among the defaults to assign to the network"

The network created by our sysadmin is "172.22.0.0/16". The minimal host is "172.22.0.1" and the maximal host is "172.22.255.254".

But our sysadmin ask me to use IP between 172.22.24.1 → 172.22.24.254 for my containers to not have conflict with other servers.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
{
  "default-address-pools": [
    {
      "base": "172.22.24.0/24",
      "size": 24
    }
  ]
}
```

And make sure to restart the Docker daemon (such as `systemctl restart docker`)

Comment: If I do that I have this error message: 

"ERROR: could not find an available, non-overlapping IPv4 address pool among the defaults to assign to the network"

The network created by our sysadmin is "172.22.0.0/16". The minimal host is "172.22.0.1" and the maximal host is "172.22.255.254". But he ask me to use IP between 172.22.24.1 → 172.22.24.254 for my containers to not have conflict with other servers.